# OpenLayers 3 interaction Select Problem

Tags: openlayers

I have a problem as a short and clear. When I use the snipped code:

```
 var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.mouseMove
    });
```

base map's mouse click drag is not working. You can see http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/select-features.html?q=select

When you select as hover from  Action type. Drag is not working. 
is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

That’s an issue. Reported here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2666

Comment: i dont check out back. may be resolved at v3.0.0-gamma.2.

Comment: Now fixed in the master branch of ol3.